# How can implement awaiting manually?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, async-await, task

As an example suppose we have this:

```
public class MyClass
{    
    public async Task<bool?> MySynchronousNonBlockingFunction()
    {
        await here ...

        return MyDialogResult;
    }      
}
```

and caller must call my function as below:

```
public async void Button_Click()
{
    var instance = new MyClass();

    var result = await instance.MySynchronousNonBlockingFunction(); 

    if (result == true)
    {
        some work ...
    }
}
```

But using `Task` for awaiting as a such, forces you to make your `MySynchronousNonBlockingFunction()` function `async`. And as a side effect you must call `MyClass.MySynchronousNonBlockingFunction()` only inside an `async` void to be worked as expected.

I think it is not well for the caller. Because a lazy developer in an application development team may call `MySynchronousNonBlockingFunction()` without `await` and then application will not works fine. I want handle this `async` operation in my code internally and not to the caller. To prevent this development mistakes. same as this one:

```
public void Button_Click()
{
    var instance = new MyClass();

    var result = instance.MySynchronousNonBlockingFunction();

    if (result == true)
    {
        some work ...
    }
}
```

In fact, i not want freeze the running thread by wait nor actually pause thread so it must be free to process other its works in another call stack again. Witch i want is actually same as the work of `await` keyword for a `Task` execution. is there another option to make this use? and what is your solution here to implement `await` behavior?

I know there is in c# some ways to `lock` an object full-fanced and force the execution stack to wait. (for example by using `Monitor`, or `Mutex` etc). And all the ways that i found in c# are blocking the running thread.

But, How can i implement awaiting manually? Is there another way to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Do you have to support .NET < 4.5? If not, then why don't you like `async`? It will do exactly what you want (though you should probably use `TaskCompletionSource` and some `Closed` event instead of starting a full-blown polling `Thread`). You may roll your own continuation mechanism that won't force your consumers to use `await`, but what will it give you? And it won't look like you want it to be - you will probably have to implement it with callbacks, thus no pretty syntax.

Answer (score 1):

> In fact, i want pause ui thread from continue executing at a position, and then resume it again to continue execution in later (from CallStack snapshot position). But i not want freeze or actually pause therad so it must be free to process other its works in another call stack again. Witch i want is actually same as the work of await keyword for a Task execution. is there another option to make this use?

That's not how `await` works, though. `await` works by *returning* and then resuming *just that method* later. In particular, the call stack is *not* captured.

If you want to mess around with switching thread stacks, then check out [fibers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661(v=vs.85).aspx). However, there are no .NET bindings for the fiber APIs, and it's quite possible that a lot of .NET code will simply break if you try to use fibers instead of threads. Then there's the whole question of whether a fiber can actually be an STA context for UI elements; I'm really not sure about that one. In short, here be dragons.

> and what is your solution here?

Well, a *modal dialog* - [by definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644994(v=vs.85).aspx#modal_boxes) - is *supposed* to block other dialogs and run a nested message loop.

If you don't want this behavior, then write modeless dialogs instead. I.e., call `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`.

Comment: @lifestyle: That's not really what you're asking for, though. You want `var result = modal.ShowDialog();` to suspend that method and then resume it later *with the entire call stack*. It *has* to be with the entire call stack because `Button_Click` hasn't returned yet. You can [play games with enumerables](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazine2008_11en-us.chm) to "implement your own await", but you'll still run into the cascading problem: every method that calls it must itself be an async enumerable, etc.

Comment: Can you show me some code sample or more directions? How "play games with enumerables"? I couldn't found any content about this in the link that you provided for me. (thanks in advance).

Comment: ShowDialog() was an example that i used to explain what was in my mind. I was edited my question to be more relative to my purpose. My Purpose is more general than showing dialog. I want cover the await and async from caller of an specific async function or void. (Suppose this function works synchronous but not blocks its running thread. same as awaiting for a task to be completed.) Is it possible in C# that implement such a mechanism? Or can i implement awaiting for a task by hand?  Can you direct me more to achieve this? (thanks in advance)

Comment: `Because a lazy developer in an application development team may call ... without await` Just turn on warnings as errors -> problem solved. `I want handle this async operation in my code internally and not to the caller` As noted in my earlier comment, `async` code *returns*, so this is *not possible*. Think through how you *want* it to work, and you'll see this for yourself. In summary, you're wanting it to be asynchronous (not blocking the thread), but also synchronous (blocking the thread). That's literally impossible.

Comment: However, if you're looking for ways to *call* asynchronous code synchronously, check out my [MSDN article on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). Note that **of course** you lose all the benefits of asynchronous code as soon as you make the calling code synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

GUI window handlers are message-driven state-machines. You must write code that reflects that.  That means no, you cannot sanely just wait, and you should not try.

Comment: But it is only an example that i used to explain my opinion. My purpose is a general concept. I want implement awaiting for a task, manually. or such a same behavior. OK. I will edit my question to be more directive to my propose.